# 404 error for php file in my angular js code

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework, server

I built an a Ionic app [Angular JS framework to build mobile apps]. I use PHP file to add a user to the database but the browser gives me a 404 error for php file.

The structure of the project is - "all files in the same directory":

- controllers.js [the angular file]
- signup.php
- connection.php

This is the "signup.php" code, included with "connection.php" to connect to the database

```php
 <?php
 include "connection.php";
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $username = $data->username;
 $password = $data->password;

 $q = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
 $query = $db->prepare($q);
 $execute = $query->execute([
     ":email" => $username,
     ":password" => sha1($password),
 ]);

 echo json_encode($username);

?>
```

and this is the angular js code [controller]

```js
.controller("signUpCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    //variables
    $scope.signUpInfo = {
        userEmail: undefined,
        password: undefined,
    };

    // faunctions
    $scope.signUpFunction = function () {
        var data = {
            userEmail: $scope.signUpInfo.userEmail,
            password: $scope.signUpInfo.password,
        };

        $http
            .post("signup.php", data)
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log("sent");
                $state.go("menu.home");
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    };
});
```

Changing the directory of the php file didn't work..!

I need some help

Comment: Have you got a web server (like eg. Apache) running that can serve the PHP?

Comment: yes i run the server to serve php

Comment: And are you sure to be on your server (127.0.0.1/index.html) and not on your computer (C:\Users\etc) when browsing your page?

Comment: yah I am sure and it is running on server Now :)

Comment: Do you also get a 404 when you browse to the file in your browser?